# Add to Python Syntax Highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: python, xml, notepad++

I wanted to add syntax highlighting for Python built-ins in Notepad++. I modified langs.xml in AppData/Notepad++ by adding this line to the python tag:

```
<Keywords name="instre2">len max min sum map str int reduce</Keywords>
```

I also added this line to the python tag in stylers.xml in the same location:

```
<WordsStyle name="BUILTINS" styleID="13" fgColor="8080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" keywordClass="instre2" />
```

When I go to Settings->Style Configurator->Python->BUILTINS, I see my list of built-in functions as well as the colour I assigned to them. However, when editing a Python file, the built-in functions are not highlighted. Why is this?

I found something similar [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331754/topic/4028342), but I could not find the file LexPython.cxx. How do I resolve this? Is it possible to resolve?

Comment: If you are looking for a Windows editor that handles Python then there is always the Zeus editor.

Answer (score 1):

Based of the .cxx file extension that would make *LexPython.cxx* a c++ source file so it sounds like you need to write a Python lexer and add that to the Notepad++ build process.

Answer (score 0):

What he meant is the *"...\scintilla\lexers\LexPython.cxx"* in the **source code** package of Notepad++.

You can't add an additional type just like that. I would recommend to simply add your *BUILTINS* words to the existing *KEYWORDS* list for instance. That's what I usually do.

Comment: But I want to make the builtin functions a different color - i.e. visually distinct from the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there ...
Just set the styleID to 14 for the keyword list you added, only 14 works.
Now you can set the color through the style configurator. See the effect here
[built-in function highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INdjN.png)
The built-in function int() and range() are rendered with custom color.

A little bit explanation:

It's pointed out [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/156/how-to-add-additional-styles-to-an-existing-languages-in-style-configurator/3) that " ... Syntilla lexers use predefined numbers for coloring things (these are the "styleID"s) ..." and they're defined for each language. You can check it in the notepad++ source file SciLexer.h.

There's actually a group WORD2 with id 14 defined for python (SCE_P_WORD2), but it's not used in the default stylers.xml.